# Issues with the CSS in this email for Apple mail IOS 16

Tags: html, css, outlook, gmail, apple-mail

I've been working on this mailer for a few months now - I'm not a coder but was able to use some pre designed templates and add in the additional requirements for outlook, gmail and Apple mail. However when I go to test the mailer it is appearing like this on mobile Apple mail

[image]

I feel like I've tried everything to get this fixed. I've included my code below. If anyone has ideas on how to fix this - I'm all ears! The code was created in Dreamwaver and then moved over to our CRM system.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="x-UA-compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>EmailTemplate-Responsive</title>
  </head>
  
<style>
  {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none} 
  </style>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        /* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0 !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        /* What it does: Forces Outlook.com to display emails full width. */
        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
        }

        /* What is does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin: 0 !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }

        table table table {
            table-layout: auto;
        }

        /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        }

        /* What it does: Overrides styles added when Yahoo's auto-senses a link. */
        .yshortcuts a {
            border-bottom: none !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Another work-around for iOS meddling in triggered links. */
        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
        }
    </style>

    
    <style type="text/css">
        /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }

        .button-td:hover,
        .button-a:hover {
            background: #555555 !important;
            border-color: #555555 !important;
        }

        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .email-container {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid,
            .fluid-centered {
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: 170px !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .fluid-centered {
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: inline !important;
                width: 33.3% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }

            .stack-text-column-center {
                display: inline !important;
                width: 50% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }

            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: left !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: left !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }

            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }

            p.caption {
                position: absolute !important;
                bottom: 0px !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                left: 0 !important;
                right: 0 !important;
                text-align: center !important;
            }

        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        #outlook body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        table,
        td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        }

        img {
            border: 0;
            height: auto;
            line-height: 100%;
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        }

        p {
            display: block;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        li {
            text-align: -webkit-match-parent !important;
            display: list-item important;
        }

        ul {
            margin-top: 0px !important;
            margin-bottom: 0 !important;
        }

        p.bullet {

            Margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px !important;
            text-indent: -10px !important;
        }
    </style>

    

    
    
    
    



<body bgcolor="#e0e0e0" width="100%" style="margin: 0;" yahoo="yahoo">
    <table bgcolor="#e0e0e0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center style="width: 100%;">

                    
                    <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;">
                        Fall 2022 update from Castle Peak Associates . </div>
                    

                    
                    <table align="center" width="600" class="email-container">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: center; border:0"> <img src="https://castlepeakassociates.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Castle-Peak-Associates-Logo.png">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    

                    
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FEF4EA" width="600" class="email-container">

                        
                        <tr>
                            <td class="full-width-image"><img src="https://castlepeakassociates.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/4e87912b-27f6-440b-9a83-d44547f3cffd.png" width="600" alt="alt_text" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        

                        
                        <tr>
                            <td background="https://castlepeakassociates.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/CPA-page-bg-600px-.png" backgound-repeat:no-repeat background-size: contain style="padding-bottom: 10px;padding-left: 10px;padding-right:10px; text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 18px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;background-color:#FEF4EA;">
                                <p style="font-size: 18px;padding:20px 0px 10px 0px;">What is on your horizon?
                                </p><p style="font-size: 13px;padding-bottom: 16px;">The Insurance industry is no stranger
                                    to uncertainty. How are you affected by current events? What are the business
                                    priorities and opportunities moving forward? Castle Peak Associates have decades of
                                    experience helping Insurance companies navigate in challenging terrain. We conduct
                                    strategic assesments, provide recommendations based on real world experience and
                                    have a succesful track record of helping our clients implement our recommendations
                                    and achieve their goals.</p>
                                <p style="font-size: 13px;padding-bottom: 16px;">We specialize in investment systems and
                                    managment consulting for insurance companies. We understand what drives investment
                                    decisions, what is required for regulatory and financial reporting and we understand
                                    the complex network of platforms, data and processes that link the two.</p>
                                <p style="font-size: 13px;padding-bottom: 16px;"> Find out how we can help you and your
                                    business succeed.</p>

                                

                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto">
                                    <tr style="background-color:#003a70 !important">
                                        <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #222222; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a href="mailto:chris.spurrell@castlepeakassociates.com" style="background: #222222; border: 15px solid #222222; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a">
                                                Contact Us
                                                
                                            </a>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        
                        <tr style="background-color: #FEF4EA; !important">
                            <td align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; background-color:#FEF4EA">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="bottom" width="170" height="170" style="min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; align:center; position:relative; text-align:center; font-family:sans-serif;font-weight: bold;font-size: 22px; color:#000099;padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;" class="center">
                                                        <img src="https://castlepeakassociates.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Castle-Peak-Associates-Logo-1-1-e1671466265911.png">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding:20px 10px 10px 10px; text-align: center;" class="stack-text-column-center center-on-narrow">
                                                        <p style="font-size: 16px;padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;">WHO...ARE
                                                            OUR CLIENTS?</p>
                                                        <p style="font-size: 15px;padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;">We work
                                                            with institutional asset owners and managers including:</p>
                                                        <p class="bullet">&#8226;&#8194;Insurers</p>
                                                        <p class="bullet">&#8226;&#8194;Pension Funds</p>
                                                        <p class="bullet">&#8226;&#8194;Banks</p>
                                                        <p class="bullet">&#8226;&#8194;Advisors</p>
                                                        <p class="bullet">&#8226;&#8194;Service Providers</p>
                                                        <p class="bullet">&#8226;&#8194;Fund Administrators</p>
                                                        <p style="padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;">Much of our recent work has
                                                            been with large, complex insurers with investment mandates
                                                            extending into alternatives, mortgage loans, private credit
                                                            and derivatives.</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        

                                </tr></table>
                                

                                
                                <table align="center" width="600" class="email-container">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 40px 10px;width: 100%;font-size: 12px; font-family: sans-serif; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height:18px; text-align: center; color: #888888;">
                                            <webversion style="color:#cccccc; text-decoration:underline; font-weight: bold;">
                                                View as a Web Page</webversion>
                                            <br>
                                            <br>
                                            Castle Peak Associates, LP<br>
                                            <span class="mobile-link--footer">2020 N Main St., Unit 239 Los Angeles,
                                                CA</span> <br>
                                            <br>
                                            <unsubscribe style="color:#888888; text-decoration:underline;">unsubscribe
                                            </unsubscribe>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&#160;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&#160;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>type here
```

I've tried switching out the header tags, searched to see if I was missing a closing tag, and tried my best to make sure all the media queries matched up.

Answer (score -2):

Add the `alt=""` attribute to the images:

```html
<img
    src="https://castlepeakassociates.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Castle-Peak-Associates-Logo-1-1-e1671466265911.png"
    alt="Your image description"
>
```

Comment: How would an `alt` attribute fix any layout problems?